# Best MySql db design for multiple Many To Many relations

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I have 6 tables in a MySql database that I need to join to each other (the 6 items must be associated in ***any*** possible way). I also need to add a "sort_order" column somehow to these relations.
Using "classical ManyToMany" join tables would lead to a messy db, with tens of join tables. That would be impossible to maintain.
The best solution I could find was to use a single join table with 7 columns (6 for the 6 items ids + 1 for sort_order), where every row identifies a single association between 2 tables.

Here is the join table i did:

```
mysql> desc relations;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| artist_id  | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| art_id     | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| edition_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| expo_id    | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| news_id    | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| press_id   | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| sort_order | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Since I am not an expert of database designs, I guess there may be better designs to achieve the same goal. What would be the best design?

Note 1: Please do not tell me that I should avoid too many association: this is a particular and precise need of the project and I just have to find the best solution to make it possible.

Note 2: By the way, this is for a Php/MySql web application and I am using Yii as framework.

Comment: Next time please copy/paste from your terminal into the question. Highlight and ctl-k to format a code block.

Answer (score 2):

1. Joins are not bad if done correctly (e.g. normalization) in performance and maintenance-wise.
2. Only de-normalize when the needs actually arise.
3. Follow the most possibly correct (and working!) path in the beginning, don't worry about performance or other things.
4. Premature Optimization is said to be the mother of all evil.
5. Add appropriate indexes to foreign keys (MySQL automatically covers this) and to the fields that are used in `WHERE`, `ON`, `ORDER BY` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I do not care too much about performance in this stage. I do not have a clue if this design could be better or not in performance terms than the 30 join tables. Any idea about that too?

Comment: @e.a. In what kind of queries would you need to join 30 tables? Your table names look distinct enough not to require much joins unless there is a misunderstanding about the use of relations/foreign keys etc. Can you give an example with reasoning?

Comment: I have 6 tables: each table has 5 relations. It means 30 join tables vs 1 (the example i posted).

Comment: Can you post an example SQL query in which you need to join 30 tables?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding: i'll never need to join 30 tables. I just need 30 join tables in my db, to be able to get all possible relations. Example: in the artist page, i will have all the artworks, exhibitions, editions, press releases and news related to that artist. And for every single item, i'll need to get all the associations in the same way. For the moment, I thought I would do 6 separate queries: one for each relation.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do what you propose.  You are correct: You'll have lots of join tables if you have lots of many-to-many relationships between your entities. But that's a far better solution than the one you propose.  Seriously.

It will perform much better because you won't have any null id values in your join tables, which means that you'll get the full benefit of indexing.

Your entity relationships will be easier to update and troubleshoot.

Whoever maintains your code after you've moved on to something else won't curse your name. In other words, you will have used conventional dbms design techniques to solve a conventional problem, and your design will be transparent.

There are lots of schema design tools that can help you generate the DDL for all these join tables. Hint: make sure your id columns are named uniformly throughout.   That is, call it artist_id in the artist table, and in the artist_art table and in the artist_edition table. If you do this, the schema design tools can automatically sort out what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you. You confirm that there are no other ways to achieve that goal other than the "traditional" one. But I still have some doubts. If I do not go wrong I'll have 30 join tables. 30 vs 1 would still be better to maintain for another developer? What if I need to add a new item? I should add 7 more tables to the design. Consider that the code to manage these relations would be in one class with a few methods, maybe static methods easy to use and reuse. I wonder if rules are more important than logic in this case, when you have a special need like this.